Is Latin iudex (Judge) connected to iudeus (Jew)
The English word judge is derived from the Latin word iudex. It also seems that the word iudex in Latin has the same etymology as the word judeus/Jew, originally spelled iudeus as the letter j has been adopted in 1500s.
Does anyone know the connection?

Not sure why we have an etymology tag if not for questions like this

@RabbiKaii Not opining one way or another, but I can think of many etymological questions that would be more Judaism-oriented than this.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
